# python3 - ImportError: No module named twython

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, twython

I am using python3. 
I installed twython on my MAC using pip3 command and I confirmed it was successfully installed.
When I run my python file, it comes up with:

```
ImportError : No module named twython
```

My code is as follows:

```
import sys
import string
import json as simplejson
from twython import Twython
```

Comment: First thing that springs to mind is to check that you're running the script with the correct version of Python. Use `python --version` on the command line to check which version of Python you're executing by default. I've definitely had problems like this before when I've forgotten that my system's default version was 2.7 and I needed to use `python3` to run Python 3 on the command line.

Comment: Maybe you can run it using `python3 script.py`.

Comment: I could run it using Python3 xxx.py Thank you!

Comment: @MeiTsukahara I've added my comment as an answer. Could you please select it as the correct answer? Thank you! Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment the response from @ajxs, but as additional information to his repsonse:

You can change the default python interpreter like this in your MAC terminal:

`nano ~/.bash_profile`

Add this to the file:

`alias python=python3`

exit the the bashrc file and run the following command:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Now you can check the defaul python version with:
`python --version`

Maybe this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that springs to mind is to check that you're running the script with the correct version of Python. Use `python --version` on the command line to check which version of Python you're executing by default. I've definitely had problems like this before when I've forgotten that my system's default version was 2.7 and I needed to use `python3` to run Python 3 on the command line.